# how to test a twitter api on your local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, twitterizer

i am using twitterizer to have a web front end to twitter data.  I'm trying to figure out how i can test on a localmachine when you have to put in a valid public callback url in your application registration.  The twitter page doesn't let you have a callback url like this:

http://localhost:3444/Callback . .

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use http://127.0.0.1:port/...

The Twitterizer example application is already setup to test locally.

Ricky (The guy who made Twitterizer)

Comment: Version 2.1 (in beta, full release in a few days) that supports providing a custom callback url when you obtain request tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of localhost can you use your IP?

You can get it using whatismyip.com.

HTH

Comment: @DannyLane - twitter seems to allow that but for some reason when i put that address [http://[ipaddress]:3434] it doesn't seem to take me to the same place as [http://localhost:3434/]

Comment: @oo could it be something like port forwarding not being setup on your router/firewall to forward requests on port 3434 to that port on your local machine? I believe no-ip like Navi Sidhu suggested will still give you the same problem as you are facing now, you will still need to forward ports. Do you have a site running on your local machine on that port? Can you access the site on that port via the ip? if you can then I think the port forwarding is setup correctly.

Comment: @DannyLane -i am just using the webserver that kicks off when you start a web solution in visual studio

Comment: @oo ok, if you go to http://[your ip address]:3434 in your browser does your website show up? If it dosen't then the twitter api won't be able to reach it either and its probably a port forwarding issue (I think).  Must sleep, will be back in the morn :)

Comment: @DannyLane -  my website doesn't show up if i use the ipaddress:3434 so i agree that twitter wont be able to find it as well

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like [No-Ip](http://www.no-ip.com/) to setup a static dns name for your dynamic ip and then use it in your api call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're integrating this library into your application I would wrap the Twitterizer API in an interface, then mock the implementation while you test.

Answer (score 0):

change your hosts file example   ;

127.0.0.1 mytwitter.com

add web site on IIS

mytwitter.com   and maps your project